# JAVA binary tree about the children

Tags: java, binary-tree, parent-child, parent, children

What are the rules for nodes in binary trees?

Comment: Don't be confused with biology and computer science.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is utter nonsense. You could just as well ask why the amazon cloud does not rain.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes != people. A tree is a data structure which is defined as a graph with a root node which has no parent and an indefinite number of other nodes who have exactly one (direct) parent node. Every node can have a maximum of 2 child nodes (A left child and a right child). This is extremely useful for several algorithms, for example binary search.

If you want to learn more about (binary) trees you should check out the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and a tutorial like [this, which shows you a binary tree in Java](http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/03/binary-tree-in-java/).